# What happens to stderr/stdout streams after Process.destroy() in Java?

Tags: java, process

I'd like to have a timeout for a process I start from Java. After the timeout, I'd like to kill the process. So far, so good. Problem is, I want to capture stderr/stdout during both normal execution and after a timeout.  What happens if I kill the process with destroy()? Can I retrieve the (partial) stderr/stdout produced so far? Or are they gone?

Comment: How are you reading stdout and stderr? How could there be "partial" output in them?

Comment: When the process times out and I kill it, there will be partial results. Yet, I still want to capture them for later investigation.

Answer (score 4):

You should have one or two separate threads reading `stdout` and `stderr` (one if you merge them), apart from the thread that calls `Process.exec()/waitFor()/destroy()`. The reading thread(s) will get any data that is produced up to an EOF. If you call `Process.destroy()`, the EOF may happen sooner, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, but what happens if I just kill the process and *then* try to collect stderr/stdout? That is my question.

Comment: You would be doing things in the wrong order, that's what. Don't.

Comment: In a multi-threaded, multi-core environment, what is "order"? Hence my question.

Comment: It's *your* order. You said you are 'kill[ing] the process and *then* trying to collect stdin/stdout'. *That's* an order, and it is a wrong order. Do what I said above. There's a good Javaworld article about pitfalls with Process.exec(). Don't have the reference to hand, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

*Process handling is inherently OS-specific, I'm looking specifically at how Java handles Unix processes here.*

It's unfortunate that [`Process` closes its streams when you call `.destroy()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java.linux#l295). I don't know why the JDK designers felt that was the right design pattern, but it certainly makes dealing with terminated processes more complicated.

It's worth noting that the `InputStream`s `Process` holds are instances of [`ProcessPipeInputStream`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/UNIXProcess.java.linux#l332) which actually has a `drainInputStream()` method that does exactly what we'd want - it reads in any remaining bytes in the backing file descriptor and stores them in a byte buffer for us.  This method is "called by the process reaper thread when the process exits", but unfortunately is not called when the process is `TERM`'ed by `.destroy()`.

The best you can hope for then is to jury-rig your own `drainInputStream()` behavior and call that for both `stdout` and `stderr` before you call `.destroy()`.  It's still possible for some data to being written to either stream after you drain them but before `.destroy()` finishes, but this will get *most* of it.

Comment: I agree. Terrible decision. They should have just let the input streams deliver end of stream, and the output steam deliver 'broken pipe', exactly as for a socket,

Answer (score 1):

For any future time-travellers - `Process.destroy()` indeed closes the streams as @dimo414's answer points out. However the actual termination of the process is handled by its `ProcessHandle` retrieved by `Process.toHandle()` which is what `Process.destroy()` does before it then goes ahead and closes the streams.

So to cut a long story short, it is possible to terminate a `Process` without closing the streams by doing:

```
process.toHandle().destroy()
```